# Netlogo : Creating links between turtles from different breeds

Tags: hyperlink, netlogo

I need some help with this basic command, as I am trying to link turtle 1 (cause 12) and turtle 2 (state 14) of different breeds.

*ask cause 12[create-link-to state 14]*

> ERROR : "CREATE-LINK-TO expected input to be a turtle but got NOBODY instead."

Comment: There is no problem creating links between two different breeds. That error indicates that NetLogo could not find a turtle of breed state with who number of 14. Are you sure state 14 exists? Just a reminder, NetLogo increments the `who` number each time a turtle is created.This means that if you change the code so that a different number are created, or they are created in a different order, there is no guarantee that you will still have a turtle with the same identifier. This is one (of the many) reasons why it is bad practice to use `who` numbers in your code.

Comment: Why are you linking to state 14 instead of selecting a random turtle with breed state, or the closest or some other selection mechanism.

Comment: Thank you so much @JenB for your help. 

As a new user of this program, i've been trying to come to terms with the basic functions of it all. The reason why i cant link it to a random turtle is because i intend to create a direct link between the two mentioned turtles. So if one of them is true, the other would be true. The same cant be said of other turtles in those breeds.

Comment: What is special about those turtles that means they are the ones that you want to link together? For example, are they the two turtles with the highest value of some attribute, or the closest together, or the only two turtles of a specific type or...?

Comment: Basically i have a flow chart which i intend to model on Netlogo. Therefore, one turtle is directly linked to the other. Thats why i am trying to create links between turtles

Comment: To avoid using `who` numbers, you could give your turtles a variable (that is, with `turtles-own`) called 'name' or something like that. Give each a name as it is created (perhaps have all the names in a list and simply iterate the list) and then link to the turtle with the correct name.

Comment: A frequent mistake with `who` numbers is to think they're per-breed, but they're not, they're for all turtles. so after `create-cats 3` I have `cat 0` through `cat 2`, but if I do `create-dogs 3` next, I get `dog 3` through `dog 5`. Perhaps that's why you thought you had a `state 14`, but don't?